# Strings || Case Sensitive

Tags: java, string, switch-statement

Need to make a password program, where the user sets a password at the beginning and the password can be entered 3 times before the program is stopped. The program can not be case sensitive.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int attempts = 3;
    String password = "";
    System.out.println("Please input your password.");
    Scanner stringScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String PASSWORD = stringScanner.next();
    while (attempts-- > 0 && !PASSWORD.equals(password)) //compares and then decrements
    {
        System.out.print("Enter your password: ");
        password = sc.nextLine();
        if (password.equals(PASSWORD)) 
            System.out.println("Access Granted");
        else 
            System.out.println("Incorrect. Number of attempts remaining: " + attempts);     
    }
        if (attempts < 1) {
            System.out.println("You have entered too many incorrect passwords, please try again later.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Secret: Water is not Wet.");
            }
        }                               
    }
```

Program prints as expected, but is not case sensitive

Comment: Convert both strings to the same case before comparison. I'm sure this is just a simple exercise, but note that password checks should *never* be case-insensitive in the real world.

Answer (score 4):

The first part of your question says `The program can not be case sensitive` while afterwards you are stating that `Program prints as expected, but is not case sensitive`, so it's a little difficult to understand what you want. But by looking at the code and seeing that it is doing a case-sensitive comparison, and that you are not happy with it's behavior, I'm guessing you want this to be a case-INsensitive comparison.
In that case, you can use `String#equalsIgnoreCase`: `!PASSWORD.equalsIgnoresCase(password)`

Comment: Sorry, where would I put this input? sorry I'm very new to java, and suck at explaining things

Comment: replace the line you open your `while` loop on with `while (attempts-- > 0 && !PASSWORD.equalsIgnoreCase(password))`

Comment: It works with case sensitivity but when I run it I get this output, not sure why. 
```
Please input your password.
hellO
Enter your password: hello
Incorrect. Number of attempts remaining: 2
Secret: Water is not Wet.```

Comment: also update `if (password.equals(PASSWORD)) System.out.println("Access Granted");` to use `equalsIgnoreCase`

Answer (score 1):

simply if you need not to consider the case sensitive just do password.equalIgnoreCase(PASSWORD)
but if you need to be sure that both have same case sensitive you can just convert both variables to .toUpperCase before the comparison

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).